# location path="" deny users="?" prevents access to domain root ("/") instead of showing RouteConfig default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, owin, iis-express, katana

I am using Katana to secure my site, along with `location` paths in web.config (as the site is a mixture of ASP.Net web forms and MVC).

My default route is configured like this to allow the login page to be displayed when accessing the domain root (e.g. `www.example.com` should show the login page at `www.example.com/Public/Login`):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Public", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Web.config is set to grant access to the login controller URL, but deny everything else that isn't authorized:

```
<location path="Public/Login">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This works fine except for `www.example.com`.  Locally using IISExpress, these URL's:

```
https://localhost:44374
https://localhost:44374/
```

redirect to:

```
https://localhost:44374/Public/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
```

This is incorrect, as `/` should be accessible to anonymous users based on the default RouteConfig `MapRoute` default.

Can anyone please advise what I'm doing wrong?  Is there any way to grant access when only the root is accessed for a domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around a dozen suggestions from this site, I finally found this to be the only solution that worked in my case.  I'm not sure whether a mix of webforms and MVC controllers causes this issue (routing conflicts?), but adding this to **global.asax** worked perfectly:

```
namespace MyApplicationNamespace
{
    public class MyApplicationName : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // leave as is - left here to clarify where new method needs adding
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Public/Login"); // the MVC login controller/action
            }
        }
    }
}
```